# Suggestions for easy to use date picker for warehouse application

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Looking for suggestions for an easy to use date picker. Something someone in a warehouse event could easily use with gloves on a mobile device. Something that comes to mind is 3 fields that are scroll-able and easy to set. Not looking for anything complex with calendars, etc.

Just needing it to have Day/Month/Year.

Application is an ionic/angular mobile application.

Comment: I don't know of any but I like the question so I'll upvote ya.  Seems like it should be a pretty easy roll-your-own-kinda-dealio-thingy though ya?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use ionic's date time picker?

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="floating">Date:</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" min="1994-03-14" max="2020-12-31" value="2002-09-23T15:03:46.789"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use...

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic4-date-picker

It's really nice.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr7Fp.png)